# AntV React. Possible to get the data currently displayed by a slider?

Tags: reactjs, graph, antd, antv

I got a antv DualAxes and i use a slider. I need to have access to the data currently display, but i can't find out how because my 'data' state didn't change, the data that don't appear in the graph still in 'data' but just antv dont display him. So i think there should be somewhere the info of the current data display

[Img of my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mckAx.png)

I tried to use the events from antv API to get the data when i stop to move the slider but there is nothing there that was what i wanted, the closest was a slider:click or slider:mouseleave. this way i can access the 'filteredData' but i dont like the slider:click etc, i wanted a onChartUpdate or a sliderDragEnd.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.